# Полнотекстовый поиск в таблице, БД MySQL

Tags: mysql

### Таблица в которой происходит поиск

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(120) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Название',
  `power` decimal(4,1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Мощность',
  `luminous` int(5) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Световой поток',
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Цена',
  `hash` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Хэш картинки',
  `width` int(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Длина',
  `height` int(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ширина',
  `depth` int(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Толщина',
  `weight` decimal(7,3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Вес',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `category` (`category`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=256 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

### Мой запрос поиска

```
SELECT * FROM `products` `t` WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST (:data) ORDER BY t.price ASC LIMIT 50

:data   Взрывозащищенный светильник Диора-450 Ех-Д/К30/К60/III
```

Как я понял, ищется каждое слово из строки запроса во всех названиях продуктов, и где есть совпадение - тот продукт считается соответсвующим запросу

Такое решение возвращает слишком много результатов, в таблице почти во всех названиях есть слово "светильник", результаты поиска практически равны количеству всех товаров. Не могу разобраться как правильно составить запрос, чтобы результаты были точнее.

Второстепенный вопрос, так же задаюсь вопросом как не использовать маркировку в поиске.(из примера - "Ех-Д/К30/К60/III")

Comment: **Вот такой запрос, возвращает неплохие варианты**  для поисковой строки "Светодиодный промышленный светильник NT-ЛУЧ Л 58 (СП-30)"
SELECT
 *,
    MATCH (`title`) AGAINST ('+Светодиодный +промышленный светильник "NT-ЛУЧ" "СП-30"') AS `relevance`
FROM
    `products` `t`
WHERE
    MATCH (`title`) AGAINST ('"Светодиодный" "промышленный светильник"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY relevance desc

Comment: И вам стоит учесть про ограничение `ft_min_word_len`, которое показывает что до определенного числа символов слова только могут участвовать в поиске.По умолчанию `ft_min_word_len = 4 ` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538347/207445

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно предварительно обработать поисковую строку перед вставкой её в запрос

```
// Поисковый запрос
$search = 'Взрывозащищенный светильник Диора-450 Ех-Д/К30/К60/III';

// Не важные для поиска слова
$not_important = [
    'светильник',
    'лампа',
];

// Символы заменяются на проблелы. Тире может быть частью слова, потому оно не заменяется
$search = str_replace(['/', ',', '.', '"', "'", '`', '+', '(', ')'], ' ', $search);
$search = preg_replace('#(\s+)#', ' ', $search);

// Фраза разбивается на слова
$search = explode(' ', $search);

foreach ($search as $pos => $word)
{
    // По умолчанию mysql настроен так, что в полнотекстовом поиске
    // участвуют только слова длиной от 4-х символов, потому короткие слова можно удалить
    if (mb_strlen($word, 'UTF-8') < 4)
    {
        unset($search[$pos]);
    }
    //  Если слово важное и должно быть в выдаче, перед ним добавляется плюс
    elseif (!in_array(mb_strtolower($word, 'UTF-8'), $not_important))
    {
        $search[$pos] = '+'.$word;
    }
}

// Слова собираются в строку
$search = implode(' ', $search);

// Поиск ведётся в режиме IN BOOLEAN MODE
$q = "SELECT * FROM `products` t "
    ."WHERE MATCH (t.`title`) AGAINST ('".$search."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) "
    ."ORDER BY t.`price` ASC "
    ."LIMIT 50";

echo $q;
```

Comment: Интересный способ, но например при поисковой фразе
"Светодиодный промышленный светильник NT-ЛУЧ Л 58 (СП-30)"
получается запрос "+Светодиодный +промышленный светильник +NT-ЛУЧ +СП-30", получаю 0 строк, если заменить +NT-ЛУЧ  на +"NT-ЛУЧ" и убрать из запроса +СП-30 - то получаю то что нужно, но вот если вернуть в запрос +СП-30 или даже +"СП-30" то всё равно 0 результатов

Comment: Тогда нужно обрамлять слово в кавычки, если в нём встречается тире. А СП-30 точно есть среди тех товаров, что находятся без СП-30?

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/jc23h53

Comment: В товарах СП-30 в скобках, потому и не находит. Если в запросе стоит "СП-30", то и искать поиск будет именно такое слово с пробелами до и после него, а в товаре стоят скобки. В таком случае можно добавить в товары дополнительный столбец `title_match`, например, в котором будет название товара в удобной для поиска форме - без коротких слов, знаков, лишних символов и т.д., тогда поиск может стать точнее

Comment: @K.Lobastov Л и 58 не участвуют в поиске. Вам стоит учесть про ограничение `ft_min_word_len`, которое показывает что до определенного числа символов слова только могут участвовать в поиске.По умолчанию `ft_min_word_len = 4`. 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538347/207445

Answer (score 0):

`MATCH`/`AGAINST`, если что, **выражение**.
И оно возвращает **релевантность**.
И по ней можно **упорядочить**:

```
SELECT *,
       MATCH (title) AGAINST (:data) AS `relevance`
  FROM `products` `t`
  WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST (:data) -- это условие было у вас
  ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
  LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Выдаст ли мне данный поиск следующую запись "Жук и его жизнь"  если я поищу "Жук и его повадки" ? Ведь полнотекстовый индекс имеет и морфологический поиск.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan непосредственно этот запрос попросту не запустится из-за алиаса в `WHERE`. Но что я имел в виду, понятно. Да, выведет, при условии, что нет полусотни более релевантных записей. Релевантность на таких строках будет ненулевой.

Comment: Я специально написал слова из 3 букв.Вам стоит учесть про ограничение `ft_min_word_len`, которое показывает что до определенного числа символов слова только могут участвовать в поиске.По умолчанию `ft_min_word_len = 4` 
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538347/207445

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan я счастливый непользователь MySQL, но за информацию спасибо :) Только какое отношение она имеет к ответу?

Comment: Поскольку речь идет о выборке то не учитывать эту настройку для данного вида поиска  нельзя.Просто помогaю  вам сделать ответ полноценным

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan я указал на одну конкретную фундаментальную деталь, которую автор упустил. А то, что предлагаете вы, уже тонкая настройка. Можете написать об этом отдельный ответ, если хотите, в свой ответ я это включать не буду, т. к. считаю это нерелевантным.

Comment: А я и не настаиваю. Просто ответил на ваш вопрос.Для меня главней чтоб читатель получил максимально больше информации.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan ок. Комментарий под вопросом вы оставили, это главное. Хотя он затрагивает скорее обратную проблему: что поиск **не** выводит какие-то записи. Когда вопрос о том, что их выводится слишком много. Вот.