# полнотекстовый поиск mysql слово rio

Tags: mysql, полнотекстовый-поиск

не могу понять почему слово rio не находится, в том числе нет результата и при поиске r*, ri*

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE articles (
->         id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
->         title VARCHAR(200),
->         body TEXT,
->         FULLTEXT (title,body)
->         );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO articles VALUES
->         (0,'MySQL Tutorial', 'DBMS stands for DataBase ...'),
->         (0,'How To Use MySQL Efficiently', 'After you went through a ...'),
->         (0,'Optimising MySQL','In this tutorial we will show ...'),
->         (0,'1001 MySQL Trick','1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ...'),
->         (0,'MySQL vs. YourSQL', 'In the following database comparison ...'),
->         (0,'MySQL Security', 'When rio configured properly, MySQL ...');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('pro*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+----+----------------+-----------------------------------------+
| id | title          | body                                    |
+----+----------------+-----------------------------------------+
|  6 | MySQL Security | When rio configured properly, MySQL ... |
+----+----------------+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('rio*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
Empty set (0.00 sec)
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('r*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+----+------------------+-------------------------------------+
| id | title            | body                                |
+----+------------------+-------------------------------------+
|  4 | 1001 MySQL Trick | 1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ... |
+----+------------------+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('ri*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При использовании `MySql fultext` есть ограничение `ft_min_word_len`, которое показывает что до определенного числа символов слова только могут участвовать в поиске.По умолчанию по моему находит слова не менее 4 символов ( `ft_min_word_len = 4` ).Зайди в `my.ini` конфигурационный файл и поменяй значение на `ft_min_word_len=2`,если нет то просто добавь его

```
[mysqld]
innodb_ft_min_token_size=2
ft_min_word_len=2
```

Подробно можешь посмотреть здесь 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html